# Request Params from especific form

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

This is my code, I want to get the values from the request but it retrieves all the values and I don't want it to do that. Please take a look. I am using C#.

```
    foreach (string itemm in Request.Params)
    {

        Response.Write(itemm.Substring(itemm.LastIndexOf("$") + 1) + "<br/>");
    }
```

This retrieves all the values , but I have 2 different form I only want the values from the form1  for example. Is it possible? I have already performed a search but I cant find any answer.

Comment: Are you using asp.net web forms? where is this code located? (on page load event) What does your view look like?

Comment: Hey and thanks btw for the reply , i am using web application and this code is located on click . I want to save the requested items with "Post" method but only from my form1 and forget the form2.

Answer (score 0):

It seems is Asp.Net you only get to have one form element running server side. This means we can have more than one form tags in our ASP.Net HTML but only one of them can be server side. Rest of the forms have to be client side HTML forms

So all server-controls and user controls must be nested inside that *main* form in order to work. So server control name-value pairs would **always come from input elements inside the main** `<form runat="server">` when inspecting a postback.

**UPDATE**

To answer your original question in order to distinguish a post you could always put a hidden input in each form with the same name and switch/case on the expected value. Further more you can use naming conventions on input fields

**aspx**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head runat="server">
    </head>
    <body>
       <form id="form1" runat="server">
           <input type="hidden" name="form.origin" value="first" />
           <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
       </form>
       <form id="form2" method="POST">
           <input type="hidden" name="form.origin" value="seccond" />
           <input type="submit" value="Post Second" />
       </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**code behind**

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        switch (Request.Form["form.origin"]) {
            case "first":
                // first for has asp.net spesifics. Because its the main runat server form
                foreach (var key in Request.Form.AllKeys) {
                    Response.Write(string.Format("{0}: {1}", key, Request.Form[key]) + "<br/>");
                }                    break;
            case "second":
                //seccond form contains only values from the post.
                foreach (var key in Request.Form.AllKeys) {
                    Response.Write(string.Format("{0}: {1}", key, Request.Form[key]) + "<br/>");
                }                    break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    }


}
```